# Certbot get certificate on nginx for subdomain on different server other than domain

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, certbot

I have my domain example.com, which points to an aws ec2 instance at `123.123.123.123`.
I also have a gitlab instance at a home server, at `231.231.231.231`.

The records for my domain are set up as follows:

```
example.com
A    123.123.123.123
git.example.com
A    231.231.231.231
```

Nothing strange here: when I type example.com I go to the AWS EC2 instance, and when typing git.example.com I go to my static IP at home. The router sends all requests on port 80 to my Ubuntu server with nginx running the Gitlab instance, and everything works fine.

The nginx conf:

```
server {
    server_name git.example.com www.git.example.com;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
      root /var/www;
      try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4872;
    }

    proxy_set_header  Host               $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_set_header  Accept-Encoding    "";
    proxy_set_header  Proxy              "";
}
```

Now I want to set up SSL with certbot. I use `certonly` and `--dry-run` because I just want to test if it works.

```
sudo certbot certonly --cert-name example --nginx -d "git.example.com,www.git.example.com" --dry-run
```

The response is an error:

```
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: git.example.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://git.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/...
   [231.231.231.231]: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<meta
   charset=\"utf-8\">\n<style>body{font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px;text-alig"

   Domain: www.git.example.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://www.git.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/...
   [231.231.231.231]: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<meta
   charset=\"utf-8\">\n<style>body{font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px;text-alig"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

If I try to do it in manual mode, it will succeed:

```
sudo certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges dns -d www.git.example.com -d git.example.com --dry-run
```

`A` zones are correctly configured and propagated, as well as `AAAA`.

I think that maybe certbot is not just trying to check git.example.com and git.example.com at this IP, but also example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). As it cant access them, returns error.

Anyone knows if I may be right, or if this error comes from a different issue?

Comment: You didn't show your nginx config, but take a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/896543/nginx-certbot-certificate-www-and-non-www/896555#896555) answer: it uses `location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ { ... }` and `--webroot` certbot mode.

Comment: The nginx config is trivial, should not affect this case at all. I'll post it anyway

Comment: @IvanShatsky I'm not sure how the link you provided may help: the error has nothing to do with nginx afaik.

Comment: You are wrong, it is related exactly to nginx. I don't know where certbot create its verification files, but no matter where it is, every request goes to your gitlab instance. Choose any path where nginx would have a read permissions (the aforementioned answer uses `/var/www`), add the `location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ { ... }` to your nginx config, run `sudo nginx -s reload` and then `sudo certbot certonly --webroot -w <path> -d git.example.com -d git.example.com`

Comment: Hm, did those steps: `cd /var/www && sudo mkdir .well-known && sudo mkdir acme-challenge`; then `sudo certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www -d www.git.example.com -d git.example.com  --dry-run`, but same result

Comment: Do you add that `location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ { ... }` to nginx config?

Comment: Sorry, misread your answer. I created the folder `.well-known/acme-challenge/`isntead of updating the nginx conf. Updated it right now, and manual mode returns ok. Without manual mode still returns same error.

Comment: Unless you've redacted your post wrong (which of course is impossible for us to determine) that response clearly states the error is occurring on [www.]git.example.com at your home address, NOT [www.]example.com at the EC2 address, so your 'think' is wrong. Check the nginx access and error logs (for the time range you did the certbot attempt) to see what requests it received and how it processed them. Also since you created /var/www/.well-known/acme-challenge as root, the nginx userid (normally www-data for Ubuntu package) may not have access; check that.

Answer (score 0):

Given that is a local server, do you have the HTTP ports open to allow certbot to connect?

Certbot utilizes the port 443 or 80 to challenge the domain, you should probably open it on your firewall. If this is not possible you can try a different challenge, you can find more information [here](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/).

Comment: Yes, 80 and 443 are open and redirecting to the correct internal IP

Comment: Try removing the location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ from the nginx conf and let certbot configure it to handle the challenge.